# Firefox Horizontal Menu Trouble, All Other Browsers are Just Fine

Tags: html, css, firefox, menu, doctype

Please have a look here: http://fastforwardacademy.com/ and then have a look here: http://fastforwardacademy.com/index-page-irs-paid-registered-tax-preparer.htm.

In every other browser... IE, Opera, Safari, and Chrome there are no issues, but Firefox does not display the menu correctly. Looking at the CSS does anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: Which menu, and which version of FireFox?  I'm using FF4, and everything appears to be matching up to IE8.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is that your HTML is woefully invalid:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffastforwardacademy.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

The specific error in question is this:

> Line 126, Column 103: document type
>   does not allow element "LI" here
>
> `…decoration:none;"><li
>   class="current1">HOME<br /><span>Fast
>   Forward Academy</s…`
>
> The element named above was found in a
>   context where it is not allowed. This
>   could mean that you have incorrectly
>   nested elements -- such as a "style"
>   element in the "body" section instead
>   of inside "head" -- or two elements
>   that overlap (which is not allowed).

You're nesting an `li` element inside an `a` element (also inside a `ul` element). This is invalid, and is causing Firefox to, shall we say, puke?

An appropriate choice of word, because the Firefox bug in question is called..

[The Vomit Bug](http://remysharp.com/2009/08/10/defining-the-vomit-bug/)

Your source code looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <a href="index.php" name="Fast Forward Academy" style="text-decoration:none;">
        <li class="current1">HOME<br /><span>Fast Forward Academy</span></li>
    </a>
    ..
</ul>
```

But Firefox (version 3, this is fixed in Firefox 4) munges it into this *(checked with Firebug)*:

```
<ul>
    <a style="text-decoration: none;" name="Fast Forward Academy" href="index.php"></a>
    <li class="current1">
        <a style="text-decoration: none;" name="Fast Forward Academy" href="index.php">HOME<br><span>Fast Forward Academy</span></a>
    </li>
..
</ul>
```

**So, the fix is to place your `a` elements inside your `li` elements, instead of the other way around.** You will also have to switch around some CSS.

---

On an unrelated note..

Your doctype is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

But the next line of source code is this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

and you're using `<br />`.

You *might* want to change your doctype to this; the XHTML Transitional doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Where the anchor is inside or outside the list tags seems to make no difference in Firefox's inability to display a menu that no other browser has a problem with. Thanks for the other suggestions, we will implement them.

Comment: Of course it makes a difference. I'm not sure how I can make it clearer - my answer is already excruciatingly detailed. Look at the markup under `"Your source code looks like this"` vs the markup under `"But Firefox .. munges it into this"` - if you swap the anchor position, then Firefox won't munge it any longer. If you're using *invalid HTML*, then you should expect cross-browser issues like this.

Comment: Detailed or not, Firefox doesn't care if the anchor is inside or outside the list tag as it still displays the menu incorrectly when IE, Chrome, Safari, and Opera have no issues and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is padding for `.main_nav ul li a:hover, .main_nav ul li.current`. Padding is applied once when you click on the click and a second time on hover and that is making the link go out of alignment. You don't need padding on hover.

After 
`.main_nav ul li a:hover, .main_nav ul li.current`

Add

```
.main_nav ul li a:hover{
 padding:0;
}
```

Comment: It's actually mis-aligned before the hover so this solution didn't work.

Comment: It's misaligned when it's active as per your second link

Comment: Correct and I tried the padding solution you gave and that didn't seem to correct it.